# iMac running too hot?

Tags: imac, temperature

I noticed my mid-2011 Core i5 iMac felt a bit too hot on the back. So i checked my iStat dashboard widget, Here are the temperatures:

- HD: 52 degrees celsius
- CPU: 49
- Ambient: 35
- GPU Diode: 55
- GPU Heatsink: 56
- Mem Controller: 55
- Optical Drive: 48
- Power supply 2: 66

Are these temperatures normal or should i be worried? I used to have a non-unibody MacBook Pro which also used to run hot(much hotter then this) which eventually had a logic board failure when it was just about a year and half old. Same thing happened to my brother's six months old unibody white MacBook.

Comment: Completely normal. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Same here, it's around the normal temperature range on my iMac as well

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm mostly worried about the Power supply temp, 66 celsius seems too much? The back of the computer feels very hot. Can anyone else confirm if this is normal temperature?

Answer (score 1):

These temperatures are completely normal.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely typical under heavy load. My only concern was if you experienced these temperatures at idle or at low usage. For comparison, it's not unusual to see MacBook CPU core temperature to go to 75℃ - 85℃